# define a bracket (`[`) operator on an R6 class

Tags: r, r6

Here's what does not work:

```
library(R6)

Foo = R6::R6Class(
    'Foo',
    public = list(
        X = NULL,
        metadata = NULL,
        initialize = function(X, metadata){
            self$X = X
            self$metadata = metadata
        },
        `[` = function(selection){
            subfoo = Foo$new(X = X[selection], 
                             metadata = self$metadata)
            return(subfoo)
        }
    )
)
```

Specifically, the `[` method is garbage:

```
> X = matrix(1:8, ncol = 2)
> foo = Foo$new(X, 'blah blah')
> foo[1:2,]
Error in foo[1:2, ] : object of type 'environment' is not subsettable
```

The desired result is that `foo[1:2,]` would be an object of class `Foo` just like `foo` except that its matrix `foo$X` is smaller. Is there a direct way to implement this that exposes the `[` operator directly to the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer is better late than never I suppose. The problem is that you are registering methods that can be called like

```
x$`[`(1:3)
```

whereas you want

```
x[1:3]
```

The following will dispatch all `[` and `[<-` calls (via S3) correctly for all R6 objects.

```
`[.R6` <- function(x, ...) x$`[`(...) 
`[<-.R6` <- function(x, ...) x$`[<-`(...)
```

Note that you shouldn't do anything like this for the `[[` methods, as these are already defined and used because R6 objects are environments.

Ideally it would be great if `(` could also be overridden so that we could create functor objects (e.g. calling `x(2)`), but I don't know how this could be done..

Answer (score 1):

In case others are also looking for it, here is a complete working example of how to do this (based on [Ian Fellows' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52066296/4620825)):

```r
library(R6)

Foo = R6::R6Class(
  'Foo',
  public = list(
    x = NULL,
    initialize = function(x) {
      self$x = x
    },
    
    `[` = function(idx) {
      self$x[idx]
    },
    
    `[<-` = function(idx, value) {
      self$x[idx] <- value
      invisible(self)  # important!
    },
    
    length = function() {
      length(self$x)
    }
  )
)

# set up method dispatch
`[.Foo`    <- function(obj, ...) obj$`[`(...) 
`[<-.Foo`  <- function(obj, ...) obj$`[<-`(...) 
length.Foo <- function(obj, ...) obj$length(...)

# test
foo <- Foo$new(c(1,2,3))
(n <- length(foo))
#> [1] 3
foo[1:n]
#> [1] 1 2 3
foo[2] <- 0
foo[1:n]
#> [1] 1 0 3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

(The return value can be another Foo object, if you need it to be. I'm returning a vector for simplicity's sake)